# Where is the correct place in the kernel to add platform-specific halt and power-off

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, halt, power-off

I'm writing a platform-specific multi-function device driver, which includes an i2c driver.

I want to send an i2c message to a custom power-management chip, when the Linux kernel is halted or powered-off.

I've tried `pm_power_off = my_func` to override the power off function, but it doesn't get called.  (`my_func` does a `printk` and `pr_emerg` to try and get some text to the console during shutdown.)

What are the correct hooks to use to add functionality to kernel halt and power off?  (I'd rather add code to my driver, rather than patch `kernel/reboot.c` etc.)

Comment: Check the platform specific hooks in *drivers/power/reset/*. For example Atmel - drivers/power/reset/at91-poweroff.c, Qualcomm - drivers/power/reset/msm-poweroff.c

Comment: Thanks, but at91-poweroff.c does `pm_power_off = at91_poweroff;` in `at91_poweroff_probe` just like I'm doing.

Comment: That's correct. In your case can you confirm the *my_func* is registered successfully when driver initializes?

Comment: Yes, it was something odd, perhaps a file not saved before `make`. `my_func` is now being called.

Comment: Also see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41596661/how-to-make-linux-power-off-when-halt-is-run

Comment: Why not add `struct dev_pm_ops` to your `struct i2c_driver.driver.pm`, assigning `.poweroff` to your hook function? Like it's done in [drivers/mfd/wm831x-i2c.c](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/drivers/mfd/wm831x-i2c.c#L88).