# How to make linux power off when halt is run?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, halt, power-off

I have successfully used the `pm_power_off` function pointer to make my custom Linux board call its power management chip over i2c (to turn the power off).

I would like the Linux `halt` command to switch the power off too.

How can I achieve this?

The (ARM) code for `machine_halt` does not have an pointer analogous to `machine_power_off`'s `pm_power_off`.

arch/arm/kernel/reboot.c:

```
/*
 * Halting simply requires that the secondary CPUs stop performing any
 * activity (executing tasks, handling interrupts). smp_send_stop()
 * achieves this.
 */
void machine_halt(void)
{
    local_irq_disable();
    smp_send_stop();

    local_irq_disable();
    while (1);
}

/*
 * Power-off simply requires that the secondary CPUs stop performing any
 * activity (executing tasks, handling interrupts). smp_send_stop()
 * achieves this. When the system power is turned off, it will take all CPUs
 * with it.
 */
void machine_power_off(void)
{
    local_irq_disable();
    smp_send_stop();

    if (pm_power_off)
        pm_power_off();
}
```

I could obviously just hack `machine_halt`, but I would like to do this "properly", if possible.

Have I missed something (perhaps in userspace) which could cause a `halt` command to execute a "power off"?

---

Update: Thanks for the answer and all of your comments, they have helped me realise what the actual issue is.

My problem is:

I have an input edge, available to the custom power management unit.  Think of it as a start button, with no stop or reset functionality.  I have full control of the PMU code (it's an ATMEGA running as an i2c slave).

1. If the Linux kernel is running, I want the edge to be ignored.
2. If the CPU is powered off, I want the edge to power-on the CPU.
3. If the Linux kernel is halted, I want the edge to reset the CPU.

Case 1 is easy, nothing to do.

Case 2 was easy, define `pm_power_off` in my driver to send an i2c message to the PMU.  Luckily the i2c subsystem is still in a working state when `pm_power_off` is called.

Case 3 is the problem - I was looking for a `pm_halt` to define, to send an i2c message to the PMU.

Perhaps there is another way, as 0andriy comments?

Is there a place in the kernel to keep prodding the PMU with i2c messages at a few Hz, *unless* the machine is `halt`ed?

The answer at: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/42576/17288 reads:

"* These days halt is smart enough to automatically call poweroff if ACPI is enabled. In fact, they are functionally equivalent now."

Perhaps there is some way of providing or hooking into ACPI - I will have to read up on it.

Comment: Proper way is not to touch it. Of course you may setup watchdog and have same effect after timeout expires.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you don't want to hack machine_halt(); the idea appears to be to give usermode the ability to react to pm_power_off() not working, at which point it could log that and call machine_halt() via syscall.

Comment: @0andriy could you point me at some kernel driver code which does some activity periodically?  Is there a way that I could use the 100Hz tick as a prompt to send a keepalive?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `poweroff` command or `halt -p`. As per [man 8 halt](http://man.gnu.org.ua/manpage/?8%20halt), `halt` command (with no arguments) doesn't guarantee to power off your machine. Reasons are described [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/42572/is-halt-the-same-as-shutdown-h-and-poweroff-the-same-as-shutdown-p):

> `halt` was used before ACPI (which today will turn off the power for you)*. It would halt the system and then print a message to the effect of "it's ok to power off now". Back then there were physical on/off switches, rather than the combo ACPI controlled power button of modern computers.
>
> *These days `halt` is smart enough to automatically call poweroff if ACPI is enabled. In fact, they are functionally equivalent now.

As you can see from `halt` tool source code, it issues [reboot()](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/reboot.2.html) system call with `cmd = RB_POWER_OFF = LINUX_REBOOT_CMD_POWER_OFF`.

In kernel, that system call is implemented [here](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/kernel/reboot.c#L272), and on `cmd = LINUX_REBOOT_CMD_POWER_OFF`, it calls:
    -> [kernel_power_off()](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/kernel/reboot.c#L252)
    -> [machine_power_off()](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/arch/arm/kernel/reboot.c#L110)
    -> `pm_power_off()`

Comment: You're looking at the wrong side of the userspace/kernel boundary. OP is already working in the kernel -- they're trying to implement the kernel side of `LINUX_REBOOT_CMD_POWER_OFF`.

Comment: Wait, I misread the question. I'm making a null edit to your answer so I can remove my erroneous downvote.

Comment: @duskwuff Now that you mentioned that, I re-read the question, and I'm not exactly sure, what is that OP wants to know (either he just misusing `halt` tool, or he *actually* can't power-off his board even using correct command, because kernel code is incomplete). I'm gonna wait for some response, and if I misunderstood the question -- will delete my answer.

Comment: By my reading, the OP is trying to redefine `halt` as `poweroff` for their machine, so your answer is correct -- it's doing exactly what it's supposed to.

Comment: @SamProtsenko, looks like OP shows some existing code and would like to use just `halt` (RB_HALT_SYSTEM) to *power off* the device.

Comment: @SamProtsenko I wasn't aware that RB_HALT_SYSTEM is not required to  power off the system - it powers off my x86 desktop system, probably because of ACPI.  I have asked a related question: https://askubuntu.com/questions/870999/halt-is-not-powering-off-as-shutdown-h-now-does

Comment: Seems like kernel here is out of the scope of issue. The main issue is your user space applications.

Answer (score 1):

On Debian/Ubuntu systems (I don't know if in other Linux OSes will work this), if you want the *halt* command does a poweroff you can create this file:

```
/etc/default/halt
```

Write this content of that file:

```
# Default behaviour of shutdown -h / halt. Set to "halt" or "poweroff".
HALT=poweroff
```

As the comment says, you can set now how *halt* should work. If you set it to halt it will only shutdown the computer without powering off. If you set poweroff it will work like as the *poweroff* command powering off the computer after closing all.